# Select OnChange same value twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I have a selectbox which adds articles to a list with jQuery like this:

```
$('#articles').on('change', function(e) {
    //adds article to list
}
```

This works fine, but when I try to add the same article twice, the onChange method does not fire since it is selected already.

What would be the nicest way to solve this problem?

I do not want to deselect it since it shows the user which item they selected before, and the onClick function is also not working well.

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Comment: Also tell us if you want to stop them adding the same

Comment: @ChrisG well, the logic to add a product is a bit more advanced since i am using a select2 selectbox, and I use jqxgrid to add items to a grid system. But actually the only thing I want to achieve is to fire the onChange method even when i click on the option that is selected already.

Comment: on change only fires when the drop down changes, if you select the same thing twice in a row, it does not change therefore it won't fire

Comment: @Pete yeah i understand that that's the problem, but I can't come up with a better sollution to fix this problem at the moment.

Comment: You could use a plugin like select2 where it has an event bound to the select close

Comment: @pete I am using the select2 plugin, and I have already tried de-selecting the selected option after the article is added to the list. But this leaves me with an empty select box and I would still like to see the previous item i have selected.

Comment: https://select2.org/programmatic-control/events you could try using the `select:close` event - that way if you select the same one twice it should still fire on the second time

Comment: @pete thankyou, 'select2:close' did the job.

Comment: @freedomn-m This wouldn't work since the change event is on the select box and the click function is on the option itself, and is also n0t recommended to use.

Comment: Not sure what you mean as events bubble - it wouldn't work as you "click" to open, but because it's on the option itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using a click event on the option tag.

```js
$('#articles').on('click', 'option', function(e) {
    //adds article to list
    console.log($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="articles">
<option>option 1</option>
<option>option 2</option>
<option>option 3</option>
<option>option 4</option>
<option>option 5</option>
</select>
```

The event will be called every time you click an option or change an option and then you can to add it to the array as before.

Answer (score 0):

Using the select2 plugin it is possible to use:

```
  $('#articles').on('select2:close', function(e) {
      ...
  }
```

This will fire the function, even if it is selected already.

Thanks to: @Pete for the answer in the comments

Answer (score 0):

Use [select2()](https://select2.org/)

```
$('#articles').select2().on('click', function() {
    console.log('selected : ', $(this).val());
});
```

```js
$('#articles').select2().on('click', function() {
  console.log('selected : ', $(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<select id="articles">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
</select>
```